# OpenCV python image translation

Tags: python, computer-vision

how can I translate image in opencv (leaving the rest of image with black color)

It seems there is only interface for rotation matrix and no way (to my knowledge) to create a custom matrix in opencv (v. 1) python

please don't send code in C/C++ or cv2

I want to achieve something like

```
matrix = cv.CreateMat(2, 3, cv.CV_32FC1 )

#now apply the translation transformation somehow

result = cv.CloneImage(Image)
cv.WarpAffine(Image, result, matrix, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR + cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cv.ScalarAll(0))

return result
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is a way to create custom matrix via cv.Set2D method.
For anywho who want to create a custom transformation matrix in opencv python the code is below.

```
matrix = cv.CreateMat(2, 3, cv.CV_32FC1 )
cv.Set2D(matrix,0,0,1)
cv.Set2D(matrix,0,1,0)
cv.Set2D(matrix,0,2,x)
cv.Set2D(matrix,1,0,0)
cv.Set2D(matrix,1,1,1)
cv.Set2D(matrix,1,2,y)
```

Beware opencv only accepts 3x2 matricies (not 3x3) for cv.WarpAffine method